# Changing value in R based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, mutate

I have a dataframe with the below fields and values:

| team_home    | team_away  | team_favorite_id |
|:------------:|:----------:| ----------------:|
| Kansas City  | Baltimore  | KC               |

I needed to change the team_favorite_id to match up with the team ids, so I used the below language to do that.

df <- df %>% mutate(across('team_favorite_id', str_replace, 'KC', 'Kansas City Chiefs'))

Which gives me the below results:
| team_home    | team_away  | team_favorite_id |
|:------------:|:----------:| ----------------:|
| Kansas City  | Baltimore  | Kansas City      |

Which works correctly.  But, I have to add a series of lines to clean up some other one-many relationships.  My intention is to say, if team_favorite_id=IND AND team_away = Baltimore, then change the team_favorite_id to Baltimore.  I thought the below would do that.

df$team_favorite_id[df$team_favorite_id == 'IND' & df$team_away=="Baltimore Colts"] <- "Baltimore Colts"

But, instead I get the below:
| team_home    | team_away  | team_favorite_id |
|:------------:|:----------:| ----------------:|
| Kansas City  | Baltimore  | Baltimore        |

I thought the '&' would require both conditions, but I guess not?

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Do you need this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(team_favorite_id = ifelse(team_favorite_id == 'IND' &  
                                     team_away == "Baltimore Colts", "Baltimore Colts", team_favorite_id))
```

first answer:
I think you need this?:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(team_favorite_id = team_home)
```

```
    team_home team_away team_favorite_id
1 Kansas City Baltimore      Kansas City
```

Comment: That works for the initial part, but I have to come back for a later edit to clean up other issues, and that’s where the problems occur. Having to use the “ df$team_favorite_id[df$team_favorite_id == 'IND' & df$team_away=="Baltimore Colts"] <- "Baltimore Colts” line is where I have the problem. I need this to occur only when both conditions are met, but it seems to be working as an OR clause.

Comment: That did the trick!